# Visual Studio Multiple window layout

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Do visual studio support multiple window layout like below.

[image]

Comment: You can arrange windows/tabs as you like. Horizontaly and verticaly

Comment: Yes it does <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605443/multiple-windows-in-visual-studio>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeap, grab the tab with your mouse left botton and in the middle you will see this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, go to your Window menu option and then click New Vertical Tab Group, this will do what you want it to do